# iPhone and iCloud

Tags: icloud, iphone

We have changed our Apple ID several times and now we want to start using iCloud.  The account ID is under an old Email account.  How do I change to our new Apple ID Email account?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use a new Apple ID that you have created for iCloud, you can use it in **Settings > iCloud** on iOS devices and in **System Preferences > iCloud** on OS X.

If you wish to change the email address on your Apple ID:

- Go to the [My Apple ID](http://appleid.apple.com/) site
- Click **Manage your Apple ID**
- Sign in with your old email account's Apple ID credentials
- Click on the **Edit** link against **Apple ID and Primary Email Address**
- Enter your new email address
- Click **Save Changes**

Comment: All other places, including OS X show my new email log in account while on the phone for iCloud, shows the old email.  How do I get the iPhone iCloud change to the new email address?